# bokeh.factor_mark() not mapping color even though code run without any troubles?

Tags: data-visualization, bokeh, dashboard

I was trying to colormap by using a categorical column like the code below:

```js
#Define input

x = df[x_column]
y = df[y_column]
#z = df[colors_list]
#Mapping color
#colormap = {'working': 'red', 'idle': 'green', 'no tray': 'blue','take item out': 'yellow','take tray out': 'black', 'put tray in':'gray'}
#colors_list = [colormap[i] for i in df['state']]
#Unique State
STATE = sorted(df.state.unique())
markers = ['circle_cross', 'circle_dot', 'circle_x', 'circle_y', 'cross', 'dash']
#groupby STATE
group = df.groupby(by=['state'])
index_cmap = factor_mark('state', 
                         markers=markers, 
                         factors=STATE,
                         )
#MARKERS = ['hex', 'circle_x', 'triangle']
#Source data
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
```

```html
# Set up plot
plot = figure(plot_height=700, plot_width=1000, title="Weight by Time",
              x_axis_label="Time", 
              y_axis_label="Weights",
              x_axis_type="datetime", x_axis_location="above",
              background_fill_color="#fafafa",
              x_range=[min(x), max(x)],
              y_range=[min(y)-0.5, max(y)+1],)


plot.line(x='x',y='y',source=source)
plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source,legend_field="STATE", fill_color=index_cmap, fill_alpha=0.5, size=4,)
```

However the factor_mark() function seems to not working properly:

[image]

While I was expecting the scatter plot to look like this:

[image]

I have read all the Bokeh.Transform() but still havent quite figured out why this happenning. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need the specified column for the colormapping to be present in the `ColumnDataSource`, it looks like you have only added the `"x"` and `"y"` columns. There very likely is an error—just in the browser's JavaScript console. Almost all of the actual work of Bokeh is done by BokehJS in the browser, so that's the only place many errors can be surfaced.

Comment: I have tried that actually. but that seem not to be the case, thank for your input though.

Comment: In order to help more, you need to update your post to include a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=minimal+reproducible+example&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) that can actually be run for investigation